# CSS line wraps: make second line bigger or specify word amount per line?

Tags: html, css

Can one control line wraps with CSS. 
For example, I’d like to wrap lines with the approximately same amountof words per line. Or at least so there is no one-word lines.

**Original:**

`Some words for a really long title that most likely will take two lines`

**Ideally:**

`Some words for a really long title 
that most likely will take two lines`

**At least:** 
`Some words for a really long title that most likely will take 
two lines`

Is it achievable with CSS?

Comment: With css alone, no: it isn't possible to prevent "*one-word lines*" as you request; if you're able to use, or work with, JavaScript then yes.

Comment: I thing you want `display:block; width:300px; text-align:justify;`, or something like that, really. Of course, make the width what you want, and you don't have to set the display to block if you're already using a block-level Element, like a div.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely achievable! Simply give the target element a fixed **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)**:

```css
div {
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some words for a really long title that most likely will take two lines</div>
```

Note that the element **must** be **[`block-level`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)** (which **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** is by default). If you want to make use of a **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** tag, for example, you'll need to apply **[`display: block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** as well:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<span>Some words for a really long title that most likely will take two lines</span>
```

Obviously you'll need to play around to find the exact width that the element should be, based on the length of the text you want to span multiple lines.

You could use a variable width, though that would cause the amount of text split onto each line to vary at the various screen widths. A fixed width ensures that exactly the same amount of text is shown on each line on all devices.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It wont work though when the text itself has variable width, e.g. in news articles. So for example one can have like 17 words, and another will have 27 words?

Comment: This won't reliably prevent any "*one-word lines,*" which seems to be the focus of the question.

Comment: @Runnick - Setting a fixed width will split the text over however many lines it takes to write it all out without exceeding the width. Every line will be the same length except for the last one, which may be noticeably shorter. You can apply different rules to different articles if that helps though.